# Formatting a cell as Text using the axlsx spreadsheet ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, axlsx

I'm using the [axlsx ruby gem](https://github.com/randym/axlsx) to create Excel-compatible `.xlsx` files. I can't figure out how to override the cell type that is generated by it's automatic type detection. For Active Record model attributes of type `string` the gem is setting the Excel cell format to General, but I want it to use Text explicitly. That way I can avoid stripping leading zeros off of zip codes, etc.

Anybody know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can override the type of data using the types option on add row.

Something like:

```
worksheet.add_row ['0012342'], :types => [:string]
```

Grab me on irc (JST) if you need any help getting that to work.

Best

randym

## edit --

I've added an example for this to examples/example.rb in the repo.

```
wb.add_worksheet(:name => "Override Data Type") do |sheet|
  sheet.add_row ['dont eat my zeros!', '0088'] , :types => [nil, :string]
end
```

https://github.com/randym/axlsx/blob/master/examples/example.rb#L349

Comment: I don't quite understand how it works, I change a cell type to integer and when I see results in the document (ctrl + 1) it still has general type (LibreOfficce) and when it's string it just preserves leading zeros but general type is still there.

Comment: @randym in my use-case the user may change the data by typing in the excel sheet or add new rows later.  I need to set type to string to the entire column. Can this be done with Axlsx? 
Kindly help

Comment: Any idea why type "currency" is not supported in cell types? I generated an excel using `axlsx`; I explicitly added commas to identify thousandth separator and also prefixed it with a '$' symbol; now when I selected multiple cells in a row, I don't see the total displayed in the bottom. If I use integer or float datatype, then I cannot have thousandth separator commas and the $ symbol prefix. What is the solution for this? pls help!!

Answer (score 6):

format_code: '@' will work for you. Please find below code for reference.

```
def default_data_type_as_string
    @xlsx_package = Axlsx::Package.new
    @workbook = @xlsx_package.workbook
    @worksheet = @workbook.add_worksheet(:name => "Introduction")
    default_style = @workbook.styles.add_style({ format_code: '@' })
    row_data_array = ['1', '2%', '3$']
    @worksheet.add_row row_data_array, :style => [nil, default_style, nil]
    @xlsx_package.serialize('default_data_type_as_string.xlsx')
end
```

Answer (score 1):

For gem versions `gem 'axlsx', '2.1.0.pre'`, `gem 'axlsx_rails'` in order to have the file columns in text type should specify both style and type

```
default_style = worksheet.styles.add_style({ format_code: '@' })
worksheet.add_row ['0012687'], :types => [:string], :style => [default_style]
```